# Node function returning 'undefined' before request completes with desired return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I know that Node is all about callbacks.  I've tried to keep that in mind when creating a Jasmine test as I learn more about Jasmine and Node.

I wrote a very basic test using jasmine-node that is supposed to GET an HTML page, use 'cheerio' to load and parse the returned HTML, and extract the contents of an HTML element.  My tests is supposed to validate the accuracy of the text returned by 'cheerio'.

What i'm finding is that the function I'm testing is returning 'undefined' before the request finishes.  You can see this in the output of the tests.  Well after the tests report a failure you see the console.log outputs.

I've attempted to use callbacks to address this and I've seen posts about using libraries such as 'async'.  I've tried using beforeEach() to store this data for the test.

I haven't found the correct recipe and I need some assistance please.

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<span class="title">Title Goes Here</span>
</body>
</html>
```

### module1.js

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

exports.whoAmI = function () {
    'use strict';
    return "module1";
};

exports.testJq = function () {
    'use strict';
    var tipsotext = function (callback) {
        var output;
        request.get('http://localhost/test-test/index.html', function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            output = $('.title').text();
            console.log("Executing callback with data: " + output);
            callback(null, output);
        });
    };

    tipsotext(function (err, data) {
        console.log("Returning with data: " + data);
        return data;
    });
};
```

### module1-spec.js (my test)

```
var module1 = require("../src/module1.js");

describe("module1", function () {
    'use strict';

    it("should identify itself with whoAmI", function () {
        var test;
        test = module1.whoAmI();
        expect(test).toBe("module1");
    });
    it("should get data from the page", function () {
        var test;
        test = module1.testJq();
        expect(test).toBe("Title Goes Here");
    });
});
```

### Output from my failed test

```
Failures:

  1) module1 should get data from the page
   Message:
     Expected undefined to be 'Title Goes Here'.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected undefined to be 'Title Goes Here'.
    at null.<anonymous> (c:\test-test\spec\module1-spec.js:14:22)

Finished in 0.011 seconds
2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failure, 0 skipped

Executing callback with data: Title Goes Here
Returning with data: Title Goes Here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  tipsotext(function (err, data) {
    console.log("Returning with data: " + data);
    return data;
});
```

This functions is returning data to his anonymous function => function(err,data), since this method is asynchronous i think you should redisegn your test to support async methods and add a callback parameter to testJq function.

Answer (score 0):

## Refactored and seems to work now

I re-structured my module and tests to have them at least pass the tests.  I'm not sure it's the greatest way to write a module but this is a step in the right direction and demonstrates a way to write a Jasmine test that checks the value returned by an async request.

Much of my changes were insprired from [Test Asynchronous Methods Using the Jasmine runs() and waitFor() Methods](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html)

Am I making many rookie moves here?  Any pros with recommendations to fix anything?

### module1.js

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var title;
exports.whoAmI = function () {
    'use strict';
    return "module1";
};

exports.extractTitleFromBody = function (callback) {
    'use strict';
    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:63342/browserify-test/index.html', //URL to hit
        method: 'GET'
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            title = error;
        } else {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            title = $('.title').text();
        }
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
exports.getTitle = function () {
    'use strict';
    return title;
};
```

### module1-spec.js

```
var module1 = require("../src/module1.js");

describe("module1", function () {
    'use strict';

    it("should identify itself with whoAmI", function () {
        var me;
        me = module1.whoAmI();
        expect(me).toBe("module1");
    });

    it("should make a real AJAX request and return the title", function () {
        var callback = jasmine.createSpy("spy");

        module1.extractTitleFromBody(callback);

        waitsFor(function() {
            return callback.callCount > 0;
        }, "The request timed out.", 5000);

        runs(function() {
            expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        runs(function() {
            expect( module1.getTitle()).toBe("Title Goes Here");
        });
    });
});
```